# Which typeface free for use with TeX would come closest to the authentic Caslon typeface?

Tags: fonts

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caslon):

> Caslon shares the irregularity characteristic of Dutch Baroque types.
>   It is characterized by short ascenders and descenders, bracketed
>   serifs, moderately high contrast, robust texture, and moderate
>   modulation of stroke. The A has a concave hollow at the apex, the G is
>   without a spur. Caslon's italics have a rhythmic calligraphic stroke.
>   Characters A, V, and W have an acute slant. The italic p, Q, v, w, and
>   z all have a suggestion of a swash.

[Adobe Caslon Pro](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1712) is the typeface used for body text in [The New Yorker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Yorker) and is one of the two official typefaces of [the University of Virginia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Virginia). Caslon's types were used in many historic documents, including the [U.S. Declaration of Independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Declaration_of_Independence). For many years a common rule of thumb of printers and typesetters was *When in doubt, use Caslon.*

I am looking for a *"free as in beer"* analogue.

[image: specimen of the Caslon typeface]

[image: Adobe Caslon Pro ligatures]

Comment: Hi! Remember that you can use whatever TrueType or OpenType typeface you want, if you switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. If you needed math support, my (non-)qualified guess is that Euler would be a nice choice. However, in general, I'm not sure if font questions like this one really fit into the scope of this site... Maybe [graphicdesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) would be a better site? (opinions?)

Comment: @tohecz sounds like a (good) meta Q

Comment: I am still looking for **BETTER ANSWERS!**

Answer (score 3):

You have [the LibreCaslon fonts on CTAN.](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/librecaslon) It existes in opentype and type 1 formats, and there is a package to use them with (pdf)latex, but with no maths support.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt Buy the font, then. There is a reason that good fonts often cost money: doing things like good ligatures is non-trivial. There's nothing to stop you using commercial fonts with TeX.

Comment: @JosephWright Besides, for $169 Adobe allows me to use the typefaces on five desktops, but not to link it on my web page. For that, I would need to pay for another subscription based service of them. At least to me, this does not sound like a good deal...